# How to create contour plot with grided shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, contour

I'm dealing with the gridded shpefile with different color in each pixel. The gridded figure looks like this:

[image]

I want to transform the pcolormesh plot into contour plot. I have tried the contour plugin which can generate contours of set of data points.

But the shapefile which I have uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7FE0kxAL8kQTEdnd2dHR21UeVk?usp=sharing) can not be imported into the contour plugin as a vector layer.

It seems that the original shapefile need to be pre-processed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create a Centroids layer first.

In this example I used `Polygon centroids` tool in `Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Vector polygon tools`. (Type "centroid" in the search window to find it).

[image]

And use Centroids as input to the Contour plugin.

[image]